# Add image to Material-UI card without a path

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I want to add an image to a CardMedia component, but I currently have it as a base64 string, something like this:

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACoCAMAAABg99fBOxrQANHibkS1KoplYAFHgUGz85g6Ggnn2ysaMXSlccHislKRm7uI10eB9piJYuPjE3epRveUuwrTNidn9ad2ZMZFxNfoOJjTsOGESjp...

So I've tried converting the string to a blob/file but after that, how do I attach the image to the CardMedia? it seems to be expecting a path to an image

[image: some props of CardMedia]

Comment: can [`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify that the content is encoded in base64. I used svg in example, just update your MIME type as necessary e.g., `image/png`

```js
const { Card, CardMedia } = MaterialUI;
    
ReactDOM.render(
  <Card>
    <CardMedia
      style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
      image="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBjbGFzcz0iTXVpU3ZnSWNvbi1yb290IiBmb2N1c2FibGU9ImZhbHNlIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNCAyNCIgYXJpYS1oaWRkZW49InRydWUiID48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTUgM2wyLjMgMi4zLTIuODkgMi44NyAxLjQyIDEuNDJMMTguNyA2LjcgMjEgOVYzaC02ek0zIDlsMi4zLTIuMyAyLjg3IDIuODkgMS40Mi0xLjQyTDYuNyA1LjMgOSAzSDN2NnptNiAxMmwtMi4zLTIuMyAyLjg5LTIuODctMS40Mi0xLjQyTDUuMyAxNy4zIDMgMTV2Nmg2em0xMi02bC0yLjMgMi4zLTIuODctMi44OS0xLjQyIDEuNDIgMi44OSAyLjg3TDE1IDIxaDZ2LTZ6Ij48L3BhdGg+PC9zdmc+"
    />
    <CardMedia
      component={() => (
        <img
          alt="test"
          src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBjbGFzcz0iTXVpU3ZnSWNvbi1yb290IiBmb2N1c2FibGU9ImZhbHNlIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNCAyNCIgYXJpYS1oaWRkZW49InRydWUiID48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTUgM2wyLjMgMi4zLTIuODkgMi44NyAxLjQyIDEuNDJMMTguNyA2LjcgMjEgOVYzaC02ek0zIDlsMi4zLTIuMyAyLjg3IDIuODkgMS40Mi0xLjQyTDYuNyA1LjMgOSAzSDN2NnptNiAxMmwtMi4zLTIuMyAyLjg5LTIuODctMS40Mi0xLjQyTDUuMyAxNy4zIDMgMTV2Nmg2em0xMi02bC0yLjMgMi4zLTIuODctMi44OS0xLjQyIDEuNDIgMi44OSAyLjg3TDE1IDIxaDZ2LTZ6Ij48L3BhdGg+PC9zdmc+"
        />
      )}
    />
  </Card>, 
  document.getElementById("root") 
);
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```